# HTC Delivery Report

Tags: htc-desire, sms

Is there a way to turn on the text message delivery report on the HTC Desire?

Does it even have a delivery report functionality?

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the "Messages" app
2. press menu
3. choose settings
4. enable "Delivery reports" (4th option from the top)